Compare and subtract duplicate contacts between two VCFs
To begin with, a clarification: I'm not looking to find and merge/delete duplicate contacts on my device. I'm working purely with two VCFs that have common contacts between them.
For ease of understanding, I've two VCFs which I'll call all.vcf and unwanted.vcf. all.vcf has contacts from unwanted.vcf that I want to remove. Essentially, I want to perform all.vcf minus unwanted.vcf and end up with my_contacts.vcf.
Technically, these operations can be done but I haven't found any programs that can read and compare multiple VCFs, hence this question. If anyone knows of any software that can perform the desired operation, please let me know. Or if the solution is to write something like a Python script, is there any relevant libraries that implements reading VCFs?
NB For context, I received a VCF over WhatsApp which I wanted to open and examine its content. However, all the contacts were added to my device instead, and with no way to reverse the addition of about 6000 contacts.
Possible complication could be due to VCF version mismatch as all.vcf is an Android export and unwanted.vcf is an iCloud export. IDK what versions they output in and if they output standard VCF with no proprietary/custom fields that can screw things up.

A .vcf file, whether from Mac OS, Android, Windows, Linux or other source,  is simply a list containing readable text, which can be viewed and edited in any text editor, such as Linux Kate or Windows Notepad++.
An example of one item in a .vcf  is shown below:
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Lugosi;Bela
FN:Bela Lugosi
TEL;CELL:2125551212 
END:VCARD

Though you could manually compare .vcf files, there are numerous tools to help difference and merge files, which work particularly well for text, such as WinMerge for Windows, Meld for Linux, and many alternatives.
To remove all items in unwanted.vcf from all.vcf, use a filter such as that from WinMerge to select those found in both, and then delete all those selected in all.vcf.
N.B.:
Make copies of the two files, and work with those copies. Check your edited .vcf on a phone or other device, before making changes permanent.

I know VCFs are plain text files, but wasn't aware of software that can do such comparison. Thanks for the info. And as I've suspected, I've run into the complication I mentioned: Android exports does VCF 2.1, whereas iCloud's export is 3.0. I guess I can look for software that can convert VCF versions, but I'm positive by incomplete conversion or some other quirk, line by line comparison may not be too useful.

At this time, VCF is up to v. 4. That said, I believe a device or service using the newer specs (3.0 in iCloud) could safely import the older VCF file (2.1 in Android). You could experiment with a few of the records, and export from iCloud, to have all at v. 3.0. See https://www.softaken.com/guide/difference-among-vcard-version-2-0-3-0-4-0/ for vCard versions.

I can't, I don't have access to any iCloud service. I was helping someone else export the VCF from iCloud. I simply wanted to examine the file, to see if he'd exported multiple contacts, but I've inadvertently added them to my Android device. My plan of attack is exporting all.vcf from phone, compare and remove duplicates from iCloud's unwanted.vcf and hopefully end up with a VCF with only my original contacts.

I think I've solved it; going through the VCF manually, I noticed the contacts are present in the order I saved them. Meaning, beyond the last of my actual contact begins all that I've added mistakenly. I believe I can just nuke the rest of the file after my last contact is defined. Thank you so much for all your help. I can accept your answer, it maybe of help to someone else. Let me know what you think.

As you wish. After removing the lat entries, you might "diff" the files to check that only undesired vCards were removed. BTW, keep a copy of the VCF, in case you need to restore them or put them on a new phone.
